# Exception has occurred: VariableDoesNotExist - Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, visual-studio-code, django-templates

Fala galera, obtive um erro que não estou conseguindo entender o motivo.
Estou criando um app web simples de cadastro de clientes com django, estou usando o vscode com editor de texto.

Quando inicializo a aplicação ocorre o erro descrito na descrição da pergunta, só que este erro acontece somente quando inicializo usando o dupurador do vscode para django, o erro vem do arquivo index.html onde esta a linha de código abaixo:

```py
{% if error_message %}  
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible show" role="alert">
    {{ error_message }}
    <button type="button" class="close" style="color:white" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    </div>>
{% endif %}
```

views.py

```py
def index(request):
    clients = service_client.get_all() #service_client é uma variavel global que instancia minha classe de serviço
    context_view = {'clients':clients}

    if 'messages' in request.session:
        messages = request.session.pop('messages')
        context_view.update(messages)

    return render(request, 'core/index.html', context= context_view)
```

adicionando as mensagens através da session

```
request.session['messages'] = {'success_message':'minha mensagem'}
```

Quando rodo normalmente com o comando **python manage.py runserver** funciona normalmente

Erro completo:

```
Exception has occurred: VariableDoesNotExist
Failed lookup for key [error_message] in [{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {'csrf_token': <SimpleLazyObject: <function csrf.<locals>._get_val at 0x07BAD858>>, 'request': <WSGIRequest: GET '/'>, 'user': <SimpleLazyObject: <function AuthenticationMiddleware.process_request.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x07AF9A08>>, 'perms': <django.contrib.auth.context_processors.PermWrapper object at 0x07BD7830>, 'messages': <django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage object at 0x07B896D0>, 'DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS': {'DEBUG': 10, 'INFO': 20, 'SUCCESS': 25, 'WARNING': 30, 'ERROR': 40}}, {}, {'clients': <QuerySet [<Client: Pai Do Pai>, <Client: Pai Do Robson>, <Client: Lucas Moraes Da Silva>]>}, {'block': <Block Node: content. Contents: [<TextNode: '\n\n'>, <IfNode>, <TextNode: '\n\n'>, <IfNode>, <TextNode: '\n    <div class="row">\n  '>, <ForNode: for c in clients, tail_len: 17>, <TextNode: '\n                    </tb'>, <django.template.defaulttags.URLNode object at 0x07BA9F90>, <TextNode: '" class="btn btn-success"'>]>}]
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 850, in _resolve_lookup
    (bit, current))  # missing attribute
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 796, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 671, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 875, in eval
    return self.value.resolve(context, ignore_failures=True)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 302, in render
    match = condition.eval(context)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\PainelAdministrativo\cadcli\core\views.py", line 21, in index
    return render(request, 'core/index.html', context= context_view)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\http.py", line 40, in inner
    return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 91, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 91, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 91, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 91, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 91, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 91, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 91, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 78, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 142, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 65, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\robso\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 194, in handle_one_request
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 169, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\robso\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\robso\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\robso\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\socketserver.py", line 347, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\robso\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\socketserver.py", line 316, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\robso\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\socketserver.py", line 237, in serve_forever
    self._handle_request_noblock()
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 213, in run
    httpd.serve_forever()
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 139, in inner_run
    ipv6=self.use_ipv6, threading=threading, server_cls=self.server_cls)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 104, in run
    self.inner_run(None, **options)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\Painel_administrativo\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\robso\ambientes_virtuais\PainelAdministrativo\cadcli\manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\robso\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\robso\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\robso\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
```

Comment: Cara.. Não vou tentar responder pq apesar de gostar muito do vscode, não me atendeu no django. Para mim não  tem como usar outro editor/ide para projetos python que não seja o [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=linux), mesmo na versão community.

Comment: Então Sidon, eu estou começando agora no python, e estou vendo as melhores opções também de editores e tudo mais, eu tenho o vscode e gosto bastante por programar em C# por la, e vi que tem a opção de usar no python então estoutestando, porém no pycharm é dificil ter esses tipos de erro de configuração, até porque já vem pré configurado para projetos python. Bom vamos ver se tem alguma solução para isso caso não vou ter que continuar com pycharm mesmo.

Comment: O legal do vscode é que em projetos django ele consegue fazer o debug, no pycharm só na versão profissional.

Comment: O debug do django é no proprio navegador, só ligar a variavel `DEBUG` em `settings.py`, não faz sentido querer debugar pela IDE (Lembro q utilizei apenas uma vez), se quer um debug ainda mais poderoso, instale a [django debug toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar)

Comment: Veja se não consegue resolver o problema do vscode, seguindo [esse tutorial](https://automationpanda.com/2018/02/08/django-projects-in-visual-studio-code/), se é q vc já não o fez